# Why is nasm telling me I can't move AL to INPUT?

Tags: assembly, input, x86, nasm

So I have this program:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 7C00h]

    JMP 0:start

start:
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX
    MOV SS, AX
    MOV SP, 7C00h

    MOV SI, Hello
    CALL _puts16
    MOV AL, LogLvl1
    INT 21h
    CALL .getinput
.getinput:
    MOV AH, 2h
    MOV AL, Success ;Echo was successful
    INT 21h
    MOV AH, 1h ;Set AH to 1h, which means character input
    INT 21h
    MOV INPUT, AL ;Store the character in INPUT
    MOV AH, 2h ;Change AH back to 2h, which means character output
    MOV DL, Message ;Move Message to DL, which will be echoed
    INT 21h
    MOV DL, INPUT ;Move the inputed key to DL to be echoed
    INT 21h
    RET
;input= es:si -> string
_puts16:
    PUSHA

.BEGIN:
    LODSB ;Load a single byte
    CMP AL, 0 ;Calculate if that byte is 0, or null
    JE .END ;Jump to end if it is not 0

    MOV AH, 0Eh ;Otherwise, set 24 bit graphics modes
    INT 10h
    JMP .BEGIN

.END:
    POPA
    RET
.define:
    Hello DB "Enter a string: ",0
    Message DB "        Grats! You said",0
    INPUT DB " ",0
    LogLvl1 DB "Calling .getinput...\n",0
    Success DB "Successful.\n",0
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0

DW 0xAA55
```

I am VERY new to assembly, and I need to move the key that was typed into the string varriable "INPUT" as defined in .define, but the netwide assembler gives me a error:

> 1.asm:24: error: invalid comination of opcode and operands

I would figure that means for some reason I can not move AL to INPUT, but I do not know why. As I said, I'm new to assembly, so it's probably some obvious mistake. How can I fix this? I need to store the typed character, or key, in the memory for echoing it later in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're essentially trying to store `AL` into a constant, into the address of the space character. It's like asking the assembler (or compiler) to assign 2 to 1.

Change the instruction to `mov [INPUT], al`.

Looks like you have several instances of this same problem, confusing memory contents with memory addresses.

Also, DOS `int 21h` isn't available at the time when your PC boots a boot sector from a disk.
Use BIOS functions (e.g. `int 16h` and `int 10h`) instead.